# jquery onclick not working for dyanamically added div id

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

I am working with **java** and **js**.
 Query is I am adding div dynamically from java code and it is getting displayed on the jsp but I want onclick event on that div id.
And its not working

**tried this:**

```
   $("#moreoption" ).on( "click", function() {
               alert( "Goodbye!" ); // jQuery 1.3+
             });
```

//added class instead of id and in a href

```
   $(".moreoption" ).on( "click",'a', function() {
               alert( "Goodbye!" ); // jQuery 1.3+
             });


$("#dd" ).live( "click", function() {
           alert( "Goodbye!" ); // jQuery 1.3+
         });
```

Please help.

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: Can't you make a function call inline from the dynamically created div, itself.
onclick="javascript:someFunction();"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document.body).on("click","#dd",function(){
alert( "Goodbye!" );
})
```

Answer (score -1):

**Delegate** with a parent container such as `document`

```
$(document).on("click", "#moreoption", function() {
    alert("Goodbye!"); // jQuery 1.3+
});
```